# Program exit with exit state 0 right after it's started

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I got this strange problem:

I write an program using Qt(*core/gui/sql/webkit*), and it works just fine.

But a few days ago it suddenly broken. The executable file would EXIT right after it was started, both the DEBUG/RELEASE version have this odd issue.

This is what i've tried to figure out the reason:

- I put a **breakpoint** right in the file `main.cpp`, the line `QApplication a(argc, argv)`.But it seems that the debuger even not reach that point.
- I try my project on **an other PC**, and the problem is still there.

Any advise is appreciated.

Addition:

ENV: Win7/VS2010/Qt-4.8.4

The main.cpp:

```
#include "adeditor.h"
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    ADEditor w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

The `adeditor` inherits from the class `QMainWindow`.

**FIXED** *BUT I DONNOT KNOW WHY*

Here is the solution:

I create a *New* project and *Copy* all the content of each file in the *original* project and It just worked.

I **strongly** want to know how it happens so the next time it occurred to me, i would like to know how to deal with i properly .

Comment: Sometimes this happens when something gets messed up during compiling / linking, have you tried doing a full rebuild?

Comment: Yes i did, i trid to clean up the project and rebulid it, not working.

Comment: Hmm can you show your main.cpp?

Comment: One other way this can happen is if you have an object with a constructor that runs before `main`, which exits your application. It should be possible to set a breakpoint on the *real* entry point (I'm not sure where that is on your system), and start debug-stepping from there.

Comment: I read from the *Qt Official Doc* that the `QApplication a(argc,argv)` holds the whole resources used by the application, shouldn't it be the *first* step that the application shoot?

Comment: running the debugger in step by step mode dont help?

Comment: no, i wish i could run the debugger and wait for it shoot one of my breakpoints, but as i metioned, even the point at the **first** line in the `main()` could not be reached, then how can i track them?

Comment: Does `ADEditor` have any static variables that could be the culprit?

Comment: No, i did not use static variables through my entire project..

Comment: How about global variables?

Comment: There's also the possibility that you have another `main` function hanging around somewhere that's being called/linked to instead.

Comment: I've checked the situation before and there did have another `main` but after i fixed this ,nothing changed.

Comment: Have you performed a completely clean build from scratch since removing that `main`?

Comment: You can start the debugger using F10 instead of F5. This will get you immediately into step-by-step mode, even before reaching the first line in your `main()`.

Comment: No, i've updated my question, what you said may be the reason, i would try it now.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: YES! It's exactly the problem, now I know it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer so it gets a little bit of visibility for future visitors:

> There's also the possibility that you have another `main` function hanging around somewhere that's being called/linked to instead. – OmnipotentEntity 34 mins ago
>
> I've checked the situation before and there did have another `main` but after i fixed this ,nothing changed. – helsinki 29 mins ago
>
> Have you performed a completely clean build from scratch since removing that `main`? – OmnipotentEntity 23 mins ago
>
> @OmnipotentEntity: YES! It's exactly the problem, now I know it, thanks – helsinki 7 mins ago